# rename from control button name(name property) in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have used a vba code to add a new row with from control button in column A.

the code is working fine but has a small issue.

I am trying to change button name property during copy but I dont know how to do it ?

For example, I am copying a button with name "validate", when it will be copied to next row I want to change the Name property (not the button text) of the button to "validate1".

can you please let me know how to do it ?

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Dim newLr As Integer
Dim lim, rng, sht, btn As String

Lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A
newLr = Lr + 1
lim = "B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr
rng = "A" & newLr
Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(newLr).Insert
'Range(lim).ClearContents
sht = ActiveSheet.Name
btn = "validate" & newLr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(sht).Shapes("validate").Copy
    Sheets(sht).Activate
    Sheets(sht).Range(rng).Select
    Sheets(sht).Paste
    Sheets(sht).Shapes("validate").Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = btn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Image link:** https://ibb.co/c0rFfv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you paste the shape, simply write the code below.

```
Sheets(sht).Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = btn
```

Because when you add a new shape, it has the highest index. So if you
find the highest indexed shape by `.Shapes.Count`, then you can rename it easily.

And Some other recommendations based on VBA Best Practices:

**1 - Always Use Option Explicit**

Because If you were using it, you would see that your `"lim,rng,sht"` variables were not defined. `Commas = ",'` are not enough to define all of your variables. You need to declare them separately one by one. So instead of `Dim lim, rng, sht, btn As String` use `Dim lim as String, rng as String, sht as String, btn As String`

**2 - Work with Long instead of Integer**

Because Excel might need your Integer to Long to run the code in newer versions of Excel. You can simply avoid it at first by defining your variables as Long instead of Integer.

**3 - Never Assume Worksheet**

Don't rely on ActiveWorkbook or ActiveSheet as they might be changed
by the user.

> The best practice is to always identify which worksheet to which your code refers:

So in your example:

```
Dim wb as Workbook, ws as Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheet("Sheet1")
Lr = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

kind of approach will never mislead you.

**4 - Avoid Using Select or Activate**

.Select() is slow

.Select() is unruly

.Select() will trigger listeners

**5 - Use descriptive variable naming**

Descriptive names and structure in your code help make comments unnecessary.

So your code would be much more clear and efficient in that way:

```
Option Explicit

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
'It's better to switch off properties from starting of your macro
Dim wb as Workbook, ws as Worksheet
Dim Lr As Long
Dim newLr As Long
Dim sht as String, btn As String
Dim lim as Range, rng as Range  'Using these ones directly as a Range is better idea.

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Lr = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A 
'==> if you would like to count rows in A, then change your code. Now it's looking for "B".
newLr = Lr + 1
set lim = ws.Range("B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr)
set rng = ws.Range("A" & newLr)
ws.Rows(Lr).Copy
ws.Rows(newLr).Insert
'Range(lim).ClearContents
sht = ws.Name
btn = "vaalidate" & newLr

    With Sheets(sht)
     .Shapes("validate").Copy
     .rng.Paste
     .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = btn
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: getting permission denied at line .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = btn

Comment: @iamnew can you completely try this one instead of your current code please. (I defined your new name as `"validate" & newLr` with double **a** to see whether different name works or not.

Comment: I tried your code and got an exception "Object variable or With variable not set" on line lim = ws.Range("B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr)

Comment: got run time error "Item with the specified name not found" on line .Shapes("validate").Copy -- fixed it but again got same object error on line .rng.Paste

Comment: Because you do not have shape named "validate" :) But don't worry I'll solve this also.

Comment: have you fixed it ?

Comment: for the first loop yes, but then there are some errors that I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `Sheets(sht).Activate` and `Sheets(sht).Range(rng).Select` it only slows down your code run-time, instead use fully qualified `Shapes` and `Worksheets`, like the code below:

```
With Sheets(sht)
    .Shapes("validate").Copy
    .Paste
    .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = btn    
End With
```

Comment: getting permission denied at line .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = btn

Comment: @iamnew  did you replace you section of your code after btn = "validate" & newLR with mine ?

Comment: @iamnew is it copying the control button ?

Comment: I can not see any button, it's  showing a blank cell

Comment: It must be that this code is inside a loop and the `newLr` is not incremented, so attemtping to use the same name again. @iamnew make sure you're using a non-existing name for the new shape.

Comment: @iamnew how many buttons you currently have in your sheet? If you already have another button pasted with the name of "validate" & newLR, then trying to paste anew button with this name will raise a run-time error

Answer (score 0):

After the line `Selection.Characters.Text = btn`, add `Selection.Name = btn`.